# Nginx arquivos Php

Tags: php, nginx, configuração

Estou estudando sobre o nginx e aparenta ser mais rápida que o bom e velho apache.
Minha duvida é.
Tenho o nginx já instalado e rodando(com a msg de boas vindas).
Criei uma pagina index.php e automaticamente o servidor me dá um retorno 403,se eu criar uma pagina index.html o arquivo texto é interpretado.
Se eu criar um diretório teste/index.php o diretorio é reconhecido mas o arquivo php não.

Desculpem-me pela pergunta mas depois de pesquisar algumas horas não consegui entender ao certo o que acontece,parece que o server não lê arquivos php.
Uso um ubuntu e instalei:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-curl php5-xdebug php5-intl php-pear
```

Segui esse tutorial:http://www.erikaheidi.com/pt_br/blog/nginx-php5-fpm-instalacao-passo-a-passo

Se alguém puder me ajudar será de grande ajuda.
Abs

Meu arquivo default

Comment: Como está o teu `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`?

Comment: desculpa nao consegui postar aqui o arquivo mas esta no github agora https://github.com/digomes87/your-portfolio/blob/master/nginx

Comment: Apenas os arquivos php não funcionam? Aparece alguma mensagem de erro escrito "no input"?

Comment: apenas os arquivos php,único retorno que tenho é o 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a solução no site da Digital Ocean(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Esse meu trecho no arquivo default(/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)
Precisava descomentar

```
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
```

No meu caso tive que configurar o arquivo php.ini (sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini)
Existe essa linha cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 que estava comentada descimentei e mudei o valor que era 1 para 0.

Obg ao Sergio que tentou me ajudar.